# Java GUI, Multiple Frames

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jframe, overlay

How do I go about creating what I describe below?

First, here is the basic look of my GUI:

[image]

When I click on `Add New Account` I want to have the GUI pop up a small window where the user can enter log-in credentials. I would need this information to be passed back into the main GUI, so I am lost as how to approach this.

The same goes for `Preferences` or `Remove Account`. How do I go about creating a "GUI Overlay" of sorts. Sorry, I can't figure out the correct terminology for the effect I am looking for.

I wanted to attempt to use `JOptionPane`'s, but after some research this seemed like it was not the route to be taking.

I was also toying with the idea of creating a new `JFrame` when the action was preformed. How should this be approached?

Comment: Don't do that. Have a look at this SO question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9554636/the-use-of-multiple-jframes-good-bad-practice You can use modal dialogs instead.

Comment: Ok. I am now using an internal frame. But the problem is that it is trying to use the main pane's layout manager to position itself, even if I set location and size.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Start by using dialogs over frames.  Dialogs are designed to gather small pieces of information from the user.

I would create a separate component for each operation you want to perform.  Within these components I would provide setters and getters to allow you to gain access to the information managed by the component.

From there I would either use a `JOptionPane` or `JDialog` to display the component to the user.  The reason for using one over the other for me comes down to begin able to control the action buttons (`Okay` and `Cancel` for example).  For something like the login dialog, I want to restrict the user from begin able to hit the `Login` button until they've provided enough information to make the attempt.

The basic follow would be something like this...

```
LoginDialog dialog = new LoginDialog(SwingUtilities.getWindowAncestor(this)); // this is a reference any valid Component
dialog.setModal(true); // I would have already done this internally to the LoginDialog class...
dialog.setVisible(true); // A modal dialog will block at this point until the window is closed
if (dialog.isSuccessfulLogin()) {
    login = dialog.getLogin(); // Login is a simple class containing the login information...
}
```

The `LoginDialog` might look something like this...

```
public class LoginDialog extends JDialog {
    private LoginPanel loginPane;
    public LoginDialog(Window wnd) {
        super(wnd);
        setModal(true);
        loginPane = new LoginPanel();
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        add(loginPane);
        // Typically, I create another panel and add the buttons I want to use to it.
        // These buttons would call dispose once they've completed there work
    }

    public Login getLogin() {
        return loginPane.getLogin();
    }

    public boolean isSuccessfulLogin() {
        return loginPane.isSuccessfulLogin();
    }
}
```

The dialog is simply acting as proxy/container for the login pane.

This is, of course an overview, you will need to fill in the blanks ;)

Now, if you don't want to go to the trouble of creating your own dialog, you can take advantage of the [`JOptionPane`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html) instead.

```
LoginPanel loginPane = new LoginPanel();
int option = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(
     this, // A reference to the parent component
     loginPane,
     "Login", // Title
     JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION,
     JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE,
     null, // You can supply your own icon it if you want
     new Object[]{"Login", "Cancel"}, // The available options to the user
     "Login" // The "initial" option
     );
if (option == 0) {
    // Attempt login...
}
```

Comment: This should solve the overall issues I am seeing with internal frames; yet I am still confused as how to create the Dialog box. You show a `private LoginPanel loginPane;` without an reference to what a `LoginPanel` is. Is it just a class that extends `JPanel`? Contains the various components that I am going to add?

Comment: Yes `LoginPane` would extend from something like `JPanel` and contained the required UI components.  It would then have getters and setters as required